# Failed prop type message on prop.style key `0` on card using React elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Im creating a card using react-native elements.
this is my code

```
return (
    <Fragment>
        <Card
            title='HELLO WORLD'
            image={require('../../Assets/healthy.jpeg')}>
            <Text style={{marginBottom: 10}}>
                The idea with React Native Elements is more about component structure than actual design.
            </Text>
        </Card>
    </Fragment>
);
```

};

but i get this message

Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid props.style key `0` supplied to `Image`.
                             │ Bad object: {
                             │ "0": {
                             │ "width": null,
                             │ "height": 150
                             │ },
                             │ "position": "absolute",
                             │ "left": 0,
                             │ "right": 0,
                             │ "top": 0,
                             │ "bottom": 0
                             │ }
                             │ Valid keys: [
                             │ "display",
                             │ "width",
                             │ "height",
                             │ "start",
                             │ "end",
                             │ "top",
                             │ "left",
                             │ "right",
                             │ "bottom",
                             │ "minWidth",
                             │ "maxWidth",
                             │ "minHeight",
                             │ "maxHeight",
                             │ "margin",
                             │ "marginVertical",
                             │ "marginHorizontal",
                             │ "marginTop",
                             │ "marginBottom",
                             │ "marginLeft",
                             │ "marginRight",
                             │ "marginStart",
                             │ "marginEnd",
                             │ "padding",
                             │ "paddingVertical",
                             │ "paddingHorizontal",
                             │ "paddingTop",
                             │ "paddingBottom",
                             │ "paddingLeft",
                             │ "paddingRight",
                             │ "paddingStart",
                             │ "paddingEnd",
                             │ "borderWidth",
                             │ "borderTopWidth",
                             │ "borderStartWidth",
                             │ "borderEndWidth",
                             │ "borderRightWidth",
                             │ "borderBottomWidth",
                             │ "borderLeftWidth",
                             │ "position",
                             │ "flexDirection",
                             │ "flexWrap",
                             │ "justifyContent",
                             │ "alignItems",
                             │ "alignSelf",
                             │ "alignContent",
                             │ "flex",
                             │ "flexGrow",
                             │ "flexShrink",
                             │ "flexBasis",
                             │ "aspectRatio",
                             │ "zIndex",
                             │ "direction",
                             │ "shadowColor",
                             │ "shadowOffset",
                             │ "shadowOpacity",
                             │ "shadowRadius",
                             │ "transform",
                             │ "transformMatrix",
                             │ "decomposedMatrix",
                             │ "scaleX",
                             │ "scaleY",
                             │ "rotation",
                             │ "translateX",
                             │ "translateY",
                             │ "resizeMode",
                             │ "backfaceVisibility",
                             │ "backgroundColor",
                             │ "borderColor",
                             │ "borderRadius",
                             │ "overflow",
                             │ "tintColor",
                             │ "opacity",
                             │ "overlayColor",
                             │ "borderTopLeftRadius",
                             │ "borderTopRightRadius",
                             │ "borderBottomLeftRadius",
                             │ "borderBottomRightRadius"
                             │ ]
                             │ in Image (at Image.js:62)
                             │ in Image (at withTheme.js:40)
                             │ in ThemedComponent (at withTheme.js:57)
                             │ in ForwardRef(Themed.Image) (at Card.js:78)
                             │ in RCTView (at Card.js:77)
                             │ in RCTView (at Card.js:42)
                             │ in RCTView (at Card.js:34)
                             │ in Card (at withTheme.js:42)
                             │ in Themed.Card (at ConfirmedCardComponent.js:27)
                             │ in ConfirmedCardComponent (at App.js:24)
                             │ in RCTView (at ScrollView.js:1063)
                             │ in RCTScrollView (at ScrollView.js:1196)
                             │ in ScrollView (at App.js:23)
                             │ in RCTView (at SafeAreaView.js:41)
                             │ in ForwardRef(SafeAreaView) (at App.js:22)
                             │ in ThemeProvider (at App.js:20)
                             │ in App (at renderApplication.js:45)
                             │ in RCTView (at AppContainer.js:109)
                             │ in RCTView (at AppContainer.js:135)
                             └ in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)

Comment: Actually I have just Checked and the same kind of error is logged again.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import HealthyImage from '../../Assets/healthy.jpeg';

return (
    <Fragment>
        <Card
            title='HELLO WORLD'
            image={HealthyImage}>
            <Text style={{marginBottom: 10}}>
                The idea with React Native Elements is more about component structure than actual design.
            </Text>
        </Card>
    </Fragment>
);
```

Comment: thanks, I have tried your suggestion yet it didn't work... the same error comes out.

Comment: After rerun npx-createit solved, seems that I was using a Buggie version

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement card in this way(from official react-native-element documentation):

```
<Card>
  <Card.Title>HELLO WORLD</Card.Title>
  <Card.Divider/>
  <Card.Image source={require('../images/pic2.jpg')}>
    <Text style={{marginBottom: 10}}>
      The idea with React Native Elements is more about component structure than actual design.
    </Text>
  </Card.Image>
</Card>
```